# What is the expected output of an LVDS IO cell of an FPGA (or just simulation) when the P and N pad inputs are both the same logical value?

Tags: fpga, differential, lvds

I am curious what, in general, the output would be of an LVDS signal when both inputs are the same voltage level.

So if the truth table is:

```
P  N | Y
0  0 | ?
0  1 | 0
1  0 | 1
1  1 | ?
```

What would be 00 or 11 in terms of logic output? My assumption would be X (undefined) in sim and either no change or 0 in the real-world depending on the chip.

The reason I ask is because there is a tool I am using (logic equivalence checking which randomizes inputs and flags this as an issue in LEC). However, this a case I would not worry about because its LVDS and I would expect the chip to operate normally when powered on. Also, the issue occurs in RTL and not the gate-level output from PNR, so it seems to me the issue would not propagate X's throughout the system. I may be able to disposition this or dig into the tool's options to constrain the LVDS inputs as differential to perhaps skip this case.

Answer (score 1):

They would be undefined, even in the real world. There needs to be enough voltage difference between them to reflect a proper ‘1’ or ‘0’ at the output of the differential receiver.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be much point to LVDS if it didn't use some decent level of hysteresis to avoid noise. Consider this picture from [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3662.html) and regard the "Datastream" trace to be decoded from the LVDS shown signal below it: -

[image]

And now consider this modified picture: -

[image]

So, \$\color{blue}{\text{what happens here}}\$ to the received data i.e. what should a sensible receiver do at this point due to the glitch that makes "N" into a logical 0 from a logical "1".

The only sensible course of action is to not change state, just as it wouldn't change state here: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, as with all components, you should study the datasheet for the specific component you're using.

Some LVDS receivers guarantee a particular output state when both inputs are exactly the same voltage, but most don't.

If you need to make an assumption, or run a simulation, then you should assume the output is undefined.